# how to resolve http 404 error in spring annonation?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring `MVC` with annotation and I am just trying a basic example for it. But I am receiving HTTP Stats 404 error. My files are as below : 
It is a maven project. Request mapping is the part of controller which is used and jsp page only `list.jsp` to show that message.

> errors-HTTP Status 404 - /test1/view/list.jsp

```
public class ADConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

@Override
public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    System.out.println("hjshjshdjkah");
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/view/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    registry.viewResolver(viewResolver);
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)    
public ModelAndView list() {
    System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@Controller part methods@@@");
    String message = "HELLO SPRING MVC HOW R U";  
    return new ModelAndView("list", "message", message);  

}
```

public class ADInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

```
@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { ADConfiguration.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
}

@Override
protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
    Filter [] singleton = { new com.admin.configuration.CORSFilter() };
    return singleton;
}

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    /*// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStartup(servletContext);*/

    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    ctx.register(ADConfiguration.class);
    ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));

    servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    servlet.addMapping("/");
}
```

}

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna can you help me sir what is the exact issue to show 404 errors

Comment: @adamb Why would they do that when they clearly want to return a view name through the `ModelAndView` object? (And render a JSP.)

Comment: What does your servlet mapping look like?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis please check it i am update code where dispatcher servlet is mapping.

Comment: @Eugenelau please suggest me right response path which i can change i am fresher for that so please help me sir.thank you

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis please help me sir

Answer (score 0):

It can't find the right response path.Not you're annotation wrong

Comment: please suggest me right response path which i can change i am fresher for that so please help me sir.thank you